# DrawerLayout menu item not working the click event

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `DrawerLayout` with Kotlin and I'm trying to get the click of a MenuItem but it's not working. I'm using the `AppBarConfiguration` to navigate through the fragments. I was able to access the Menu by using `navView.menu.findItem` to set the visibility on or off, but not with the onClick.

This is the Activity :

```
class MasterDrawer : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_master_drawer)
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    Hawk.init(this).build();


    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    var view = navView.getHeaderView(0);

    var user : UserTokenModel = Hawk.get("usr");

    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email).text = user.Email;
    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name).text = user.Name;

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)


    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_new_service,R.id.nav_service, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_make_money
        ), drawerLayout
    )


    //setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

   /* val value = Hawk.get<UserDataLogin>("usr");
    if(value.UserTokenModel.UserType == 1){
        navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_gallery).isVisible = false;
    }*/

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
     Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return  true;
}
```

}

Comment: Do the IDs of your menu items match the IDs I'm your navigation graph (that's how they are tied together)? Please include both your navigation graph and menu XML.

Comment: yes, but the thing is, I dont wanna navigate, I wanna make one of them a "Logout" so I need to capture the click on the menu item! The navigation is too extensive

Comment: Why didn't you say that in your question? It is always best to say what you are trying to accomplish as that will help everyone in determining the best way to achieve that goal.